# subtracting the value of strings

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to understand the following code. But I was having a hard time finding anything so I want to make sure I'm understanding it correctly. So please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
string choice = txtProduct.Text.ToUpper();
char coordX = choice[0];
int indexX = coordX - 'A';
```

What I think is happening is that each string letter (A, B, C etc..) has a value so `coordX - 'A';` is just subtracting those values.

So if the user entered "A" it would be 'A' - 'A' which would be 0
if the user entered "B" it would be 'B' - 'A' which would be 1. 
etc.

Comment: Have you run the code to check?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Note that 'A' and 'a' have different values. If you enter "A" you will get 0. What's the problem?

Comment: And the code is relying on the characters all being in a range of consecutively numbered letters in an order that is useful, specifically either uppercase letters or lowercase letters in the [Basic Latin alphabet](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.2.0/charts/CodeCharts.pdf). It could work in that particular program. (It wouldn't work for typical English published texts, like, say, the _New York Times._)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is really happening is when you run this line:

```
int indexX = coordX - 'A';
```

it casts your Char to its ASCII number and then subtracts the ASCIIs and returns the result...

This is probably more clrear:

```
int indexX = (int)coordX - (int)'A';
```

So: 'A' is 65 and 'B' = 66 in ASCII, so that's how you get the result you see..

Comment: Not ASCII, Unicode/[UTF-16 code units](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx)(one or two per Unicode codepoint).

Answer (score 1):

You right,
this code return you index of the letter in alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, U r correct. Perhaps its written with an intention to find first character's sequence order as per abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz